# Adding separators within a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios

How is it possible that I add this sort of separators within a table cell?

[image: Shot from Apple's option to Add a New Contact in iPhone's address book]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or I would suggest you to use 1px gray line image to draw those lines in cell instead of using entire image in cell.

Answer (score 2):

Using an image as background for the cell. Make sure you are returning the image's height in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` so it fits nicely.